# Itext work with android runtime error happen

Tags: android, itext, itextg

I am trying to generate pdf using android app. So I used itext java library and got an error:

```
04-11 14:32:50.406: E/dalvikvm(7771): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.Font', referenced from method ceylon.linux.androidpdf.MainActivity.<clinit>

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button_pdf;

    private static String FILE = "FirstPdf.pdf";
    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.BOLD);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_pdf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pdf);
        button_pdf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                      Document document = new Document();
                      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
                      document.open();
                      addMetaData(document);
                      addTitlePage(document);
                      addContent(document);
                      document.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
    }

    private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
        document.addTitle("My first PDF");
        document.addSubject("Using iText");
        document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
        document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
        document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
    }

    private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
            throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        // We add one empty line
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        // Lets write a big header
        preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document", catFont));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
        preface.add(new Paragraph(
                "Report generated by: " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", " + new Date(), //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
                smallBold));
        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
        preface.add(new Paragraph(
                "This document describes something which is very important ",
                smallBold));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

        preface.add(new Paragraph(
                "This document is a preliminary version and not subject to your license agreement or any other agreement with vogella.com ;-).",
                redFont));

        document.add(preface);
        // Start a new page
        document.newPage();
    }

    private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("First Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Chapter");

        // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
        Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
        Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 2", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 1"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 2"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 3"));

        // add a list
        createList(subCatPart);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(paragraph, 5);
        subCatPart.add(paragraph);

        // add a table
        createTable(subCatPart);

        // now add all this to the document
        document.add(catPart);

        // Next section
        anchor = new Anchor("Second Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("Second Chapter");

        // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
        catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("This is a very important message"));

        // now add all this to the document
        document.add(catPart);

    }

    private static void createTable(Section subCatPart)
            throws BadElementException {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

        // t.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        // t.setPadding(4);
        // t.setSpacing(4);
        // t.setBorderWidth(1);

        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 1"));

        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 2"));

        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 3"));

        table.addCell(c1);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        table.addCell("1.0");
        table.addCell("1.1");
        table.addCell("1.2");
        table.addCell("2.1");
        table.addCell("2.2");
        table.addCell("2.3");

        subCatPart.add(table);

    }

    private static void createList(Section subCatPart) {
        List list = new List(true, false, 10);
        list.add(new ListItem("First point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Second point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Third point"));
        subCatPart.add(list);
    }

    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }
}
```

I have setup classpath varaibles using eclipse. There is no syntax error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have u added .jar to YourProject/lib/ ?

Comment: yep and i setup class path

Comment: Try checking the export option in included library.

Comment: Are you using the Java version of iText or the Android port iTextG?

Comment: i used iTextG.But now no need use itextG.Google have implemented it all